# Difference between Factory pattern and conditional Class?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, error-handling, factory

I have some questions on the Factory pattern, I'll try to illustrate them using the example of handling HTTP errors in JS.

As far as I know, a "proper" factory would instance different ErrorXXX classes depending on the arguments passed to the Factory, like so:

```
    class HTTPError {
        createError(code) {
          if (code === 'NOT_FOUND') {
            return new Error404()
          } else if (code === 'NOT_AUTH') {
            return new Error401()
          }
    
          // etc....
    
        }
    }
```

But since in this example all of the classes will have the same properties you could have the conditional assigning values to those properties in a single class, instead of instantiating many different classes

```
    class HTTPError {
      createError(code) {
        let status = 500
        let message = 'Server error'

        if (code === 'NOT_FOUND') {
          status = 404
          message = 'Page not found'
        } else if (code === 'NOT_AUTH') {
          status = 401
          message = 'Resource not authorized'
        }

        // etc...

        return {status, message}
      }
    }
```

My questions are:

1. What are the different purposes of these two patterns?
2. Which one would be better suited for the task in the example?
3. Does the second pattern have a name?

Comment: Why does your factory function live on a `HttpError` class? And what is a "conditional class"?

Comment: For the first question: Just a preference, javascript classes are sintactic sugar over constructor functions in the end. It just reads more naturally to me


As for the "conditional class" sorry for not clarifying, I meant a class that procedurally assigns values to properties based on a conditional statement (the second example)

Comment: But it does't assign class properties, it does create a new object (using object literal syntax). Really no function should live on a `class` that doesn't use at least one instance property (through `this`) - if your class has no state it should not be a `class` but a plain object. If you come from a Java mindset where everything must live in a `class`, at least use `static` methods for factory functions.

Comment: So from what I gather, the better options would be: Putting the conditional into a class constructor or just turning httpError into a function that returns an object (kind of like a module pattern?)

Comment: Yes, these would make more sense than your current code, and will have clearer tradeoffs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, it definitely cleared up my doubts. As a last question, could you elaborate a bit on what those tradeoffs would be? I'd like to be sure that I understand it correctly

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the code of the better options? I'd be happy to write an answer then